# Textures visible in render but not in UV map

Tags: uv-image-editor

I am a newbie to Blender, just starting out with UV mapping of objects.  I'm using Blender Render engine.  I created some meshes that I UV mapped and added textures to.  They look beautiful when rendered, but the textures aren't displaying on the UV map. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

This is a screenshot showing my rendered image with the texture image and path shown on the right:

[image]

And here is the corresponding UV map for that rendered image:

[image]

As you can see, the UV map is empty! Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to tell blender which image to display in the uv/image editor.

As seen in the following image:
[image]